# Getting error 401 while sending push notification in fcm rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase-cloud-messaging, rubygems

This is my code in push_notification model

```
 belongs_to :push_notificable, polymorphic: true
 validates :remarks, presence:true
 before_create :send_push_notification




def send_push_notification
      device_id = get_device_id
      if device_id.present? 
        fcm_client = FCM.new(ENV['AAAAzWU3na4:APA91bEDFQ2q37C4d41nPrEcRqHJotUoohjCkYcWjfNr2CS5k-VR4YGX9rpF5mqhkQCke_061hZvLwlqCd8mbqg2L9KbOH4mveFmtbYcVHW1c-8yCrML9Sj0uwwes56i6NFxgkaKxEgh'])
        options = { priority: 'high',
                    data: {
                      message: remarks,
                      notify_type: "#{notify_type}",
                      account_id: account_id
                    },
                    notification: {
                    body: remarks,
                    sound: 'default'
                    }
                  }
        registration_id = device_id
        res = fcm_client.send(registration_id, options)

      end
    rescue Exception => e
      e
    end

    def get_device_id
       device_id = AccountBlock::Account.find_by(id: push_notificable.account_id).device_id
    end
```

this is the response I am getting

{:body=>"\n\nINVALID_KEY\n\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n

## INVALID_KEY

\n

### Error 401

\n\n\n", :headers=>{"content-type"=>"text/html; charset=UTF-8", "content-encoding"=>"gzip", "date"=>"Thu, 09 Feb 2023 05:53:03 GMT", "expires"=>"Thu, 09 Feb 2023 05:53:03 GMT", "cache-control"=>"private, max-age=0", "x-content-type-options"=>"nosniff", "x-frame-options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "content-security-policy"=>"frame-ancestors 'self'", "x-xss-protection"=>"1; mode=block", "server"=>"GSE", "alt-svc"=>"h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000", "transfer-encoding"=>"chunked"}, :status_code=>401, :response=>"There was an error authenticating the sender account."}

Answer (score 1):

The 401 error is an authentication error and usually indicates that the API key used in the Authorization header of the request is invalid. Please check that you are using the right Server API key as seen under [Firebase Console > [Project] >Project Settings > Cloud Messaging](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging/) section. You can check the validity of the Server key through a cURL command explained in this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#checkAPIkey).

Comment: I was using the fcm key expicitly on with "" double quotes which changing to single '' made it work, I don't know why I happened. thanks for response btw.